# how to use node-compiler, getting "ERROR: trying to use package.json variables, but not setup to do so"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am struggling to create an executable distribution of my nodejs project. I want to send an executable similar as we do with executable jar with Tomcat embbeded. I read

```
Node Compiler is a command-line utility that compiles your Node.js application into a single executable file.
```

in https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-compile

After installed it throw npm, I tried:

```
nodejs my-project-nodejs # node-compiler server.js
....> ERROR: trying to use package.json variables, but not setup to do so!
```

so, my straight question is: what am I missing in my package.json?

Plus that, I am using MongoDb. I believe I will not face issue if my costumer download and isntall MongoDb begore executing the executable nodejs project. I am comenting it because I read in same url:

```
but by using default nexe, we could not easily produce a working binary which with with monogoose + express.js
```

As far as I understood, since I am trying to use node-compile instead of pure nexe I will not face issues with MongoDb.

server.js

```
// Load required packages
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var userController = require('./controllers/user');
var authController = require('./controllers/auth');
var oauth2Controller = require('./controllers/oauth2');
var clientController = require('./controllers/client');

var cartaoController = require('./controllers/cartao');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/my-db');

// Create our Express application
var app = express();

// Set view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Use the body-parser package in our application
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// Use express session support since OAuth2orize requires it
app.use(session({
  secret: 'Super Secret Session Key',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));

// Use the passport package in our application
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Create our Express router
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/cartoes')
.post(cartaoController.postCartoes);
 // .post(authController.isAuthenticated, cartaoController.postCartoes);

router.route('/users')
  .post(userController.postUsers)
  .get(authController.isAuthenticated, userController.getUsers);

router.route('/clients')
  .post(authController.isAuthenticated, clientController.postClients)
  .get(authController.isAuthenticated, clientController.getClients);

router.route('/oauth2/authorize')
  .get(authController.isAuthenticated, oauth2Controller.authorization)
  .post(authController.isAuthenticated, oauth2Controller.decision);

router.route('/oauth2/token')
  .post(authController.isClientAuthenticated, oauth2Controller.token);

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(3000);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app-dmz",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.0.2",
    "ejs": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.1.1",
    "express-session": "^1.6.1",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.8",
    "node-rest-client": "^2.5.0",
    "oauth2orize": "^1.0.1",
    "passport": "^0.2.0",
    "passport-http": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "reqclient": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

one of the models

```
// Load required packages
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Define our client schema
var ClientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  id: { type: String, required: true },
  secret: { type: String, required: true },
  userId: { type: String, required: true }
});

// Export the Mongoose model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema);
```

Comment: I am still looking carefully for answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Just got the same warning when trying to bundle my app with *nexe*.

To solve this, I simply had to add a `"nexe"` entry in my package.json file, as the *nexe* documentation suggests:
https://github.com/nexe/nexe/tree/V1-EOL#packagejson-inclusion

```
"nexe": {
    "input": "./bin/nexe",
    "output": "nexe^$",
    "temp": "src",
    "browserify": {
        "requires": [],
        "excludes": [],
        "paths": []
    },
    "runtime": {
        "framework": "node",
        "version": "5.6.0",
        "js-flags": "--use_strict",
        "ignoreFlags": true
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the link target does not exist anymore but can still be found here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe#packagejson-inclusion

Comment: @Xan-Kun Clark-Davis Thanks for pointing that. I have updated the link to nexe v1 documentation.